# How to prove that this series $f(z)=1+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}2^{-k z}$ converges using the theory of continued fractions?

Tags: reference-request, continued-fractions

Consider the following series
\begin{equation}
f(z)=1+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{k z}} =1+ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left( \prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2^{z}} \right)
\end{equation}
Using Euler's continued fraction formula we can express this as a continued fraction
\begin{equation*}
  f(z)= \cfrac{1}{
          1- \cfrac{2^{-z}}{
          1+2^{-z}- \cfrac{2^{-z}}{
          1+2^{-z}- \cfrac{2^{-z}}{
          1+2^{-z} - \ddots}}}}
\end{equation*}
or more succinctly
\begin{align*}
f(z)=\newcommand{\bigk}{\mathop{\Huge\vcenter{\hbox{K}}}}\left(1-\bigk_{k=1}^{\infty }\frac{-2^{-z}}{1+2^{-z}}\right)^{-1}
\end{align*}
Note that $z \in \mathbb{C}$.

We know that $f(z)$ converges for $\Re{z}>0$. How can we prove this using only the theory of continued fractions? Which theorems guarantee this?

Thanks.

*NOTE:* There is now a similar question at [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/84079/how-to-find-the-region-of-convergence-of-this-series-using-the-theory-of-continue).

Comment: $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{z}}$ trivially diverges.

Comment: @J.M.: It appears from the $\sum\prod$ form that it should be $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{2^{kz}}$.

Comment: @J.M. forgot the $k$, now corrected.

Comment: In that case, the convergence region ought to be $\Re z > 0$, no?

Comment: @J.M. yes.${{{{{}}}}}$

Comment: Śleszyński–Pringsheim theorem?

Comment: @Noud $|1+2^{-z}|\geq|2^{-z}|+1$ only works for $\Im{z}=0$ it seems...

Comment: You can try Van Vleck after applying an equivalence transformation...

Comment: OK, I'll try that.